# What method is calling after launching application been killed IOS?

Tags: ios, ios5, ios4

I have an app which receive a NSLocalNotifications. It is ok but when I trigger the notifications and delete the app from the app list ,after double tap on home button, it receives the local notification it is ok. The problem is which method is called when launching  this killed app?

Comment: I do not get what you mean by accepts?

Comment: You haven't accepted any answers to your previous questions. It shows on your tag. People will be apprehensive about answering you.

Answer (score 0):

Local notification will not launch your app (see docs quote), you can expect the usual delegate call when launching the app

> An application can create and schedule a local notification, and the operating system then delivers it at the schedule date and time. **If it delivers it when the application is not active in the foreground, it displays an alert, badges the application icon, or plays a sound—whatever is specified in the UILocalNotification object**. If the application is running in the foreground, there is no alert, badging, or sound; instead, the application:didReceiveLocalNotification: method is called if the delegate implements it.